# Laravel 5.1 : Migrate existing database

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

I migrated my database structure into Laravel using `php artisan migrate:generate` command with the help of the extension above. But there's a small problem, my primary key's aren't named as id, I rather used a different convention by adding a prefix for each of them like user_id, product_id, photo_id, etc. All of these are auto incremented, of course.

Here's my current create_users_table.php file inside my migrations folder. I defined user_id to override the default id option, is that the correct use?

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->primary('user_id');
          $table->integer('user_id', true);
          $table->string('name', 500);
          $table->string('email', 500);
          $table->string('password', 500);
      }
    );
}


/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
}
```

I read that I need to add something like below, but I'm not sure where to define `protected $primaryKey` since my class extends Migration rather than Eloquent.

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Eloquent {

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

}
```

I'm getting the following error when I go to /auth/login page, which I think causes because of the user_id usage rather than id. How can I fix it?

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 5 limit 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify your non-default primary key in your `User` model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

You will need to do this for all Models that don't use `id` as their primary key.

Comment: No problem. You'll find life is easier if you follow Laravel conventions like using `id` primary keys, but when you're porting applications like yours sometimes it makes sense to break them. In most places, Laravel has ways to accommodate this.

Comment: I agree with you. I would have used Laravel's conventions if I hadn't created my database structure before.